# Навигация к обработчику запроса/команды

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper, mediatr

В своём в веб-приложении использую [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR), который реализует паттерн "Посредник".

Очень большое неудобство — затрудняется навигация, можно быстро перейти к запросу/команде — но основная логика находится в обработчике (handler), а вот именно к нему переходить довольно неудобно.

Вот типичный кейс.

Есть некоторый контроллер:

```
public class CorrespondentController : BaseApiController
{
    public CorrespondentController(IMediator mediator)
        : base(mediator)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<object> All(AllCorrespondentsQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var accounts = await this.Mediator.Send(query, cancellationToken);
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

И в один клик можно перейти к запросу AllCorrespondentsQuery. А вот как перейти к обработчику AllCorrespondentsHandler?

Я не рассматриваю вариант, когда мы будем искать через find all references нужный класс — он там конечно найдётся, но умственных усилий на чтение и поиск нужного класса, а также количество кликов и движений мышкой будет очень большим.

На текущий момент я пользуюсь хоткеем Ctrl + [, Ctrl + s ("перейти к файлу") — и в окне solution explorer тыкаю в нужный файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется, это самое быстрое, что только возможно.

Также есть вариант использовать переходы по ссылкам:

```
/// <see cref="AllCorrespondentsHandler"/>
```

, но это выглядит скорее костылём.

Также, поскольку у меня студия всегда идёт в комплекте с решарпером, я пробовал воспользоваться хоткеем [navigate | related files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Related_Files.html) — однако, из коробки эта штука не работает, а как настроить - информации крайне мало в сети (ну [вот разве что](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5331280/5752652))

И последний способ, который я знаю - это расположить query/command и handler в одном файле (можете [посмотреть](https://github.com/gothinkster/aspnetcore-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/Conduit/Features/Articles/Edit.cs#L43) пример в [реальном cqrs приложении](https://github.com/gothinkster/aspnetcore-realworld-example-app.git) на гитхабе), но мне этот способ не подходит, так как я придерживаюсь принципа "каждому (публичному) классу - отдельный файл"

Comment: Не совсем понял - вам надо увидеть класс или открыть файл? Если первое, то есть стандартная кнопка F12, я дублирую её сочетанием Ctrl+Click. Если, конечно, решарпер всё не поменял под себя. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-and-edit-code-by-using-peek-definition-alt-plus-f12?view=vs-2017

Comment: @vusaldev перейти к классу. Но только я могу перейти по crtl+клику к query, а хочу перейти к handler.

Answer (score 0):

В общем я остановился на таком варианте. В одной и той же папке находятся файлы Query, Result, Handler и т.п. по потребности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При необходимости перейти к обработчику - нужно кликнуть по названию папки и выбрать куда хочется осуществить переход:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, кому-то пригодится.